# Slow down a loop or create an animation?

Tags: javascript, loops

I am creating a slot machine and I need to slow down the loops or create some sort of animation so I can see the images moving on the screen.

I have done several tests and looks like everything is working, I also included not necessary image changes during the process but nothing slow it down, I can only see the current and the last picture, despite the loop has run for over a thousand times.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var i, dicepic;
  var itotal = ktotal = ltotal = jtotal = totalgeral = 0;
  var dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;

  for (i = 0; i < dice; i++) {
    itotal++;
    totalgeral++;

    var k;
    for (k = 1; k < 7; k++) {
      ktotal++;
      totalgeral++;
      document.getElementById("first-picture" + k).src = 'images/empire.jpg';
    }

    var l;
    for (l = 1; l < 7; l++) {
      ltotal++;
      totalgeral++;
      document.getElementById("first-picture" + l).src = 'images/black.jpg';
    }

    var j;
    for (j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
      jtotal++;
      totalgeral++;
      var dicepic = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1;
      document.getElementById("first-picture" + j).src = 'images/image' + dicepic + '.jpg';
      document.getElementById("vari1").innerHTML = "Value of i is: " + i;
      document.getElementById("vari2").innerHTML = "Value of Dice is: " + dice;
      document.getElementById("pic-code-" + j).innerHTML = "Code is: " + dicepic;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("vari3").innerHTML = "Value of Dice is: " + dice;
  document.getElementById("loop-i").innerHTML = "Loop I: " + itotal;
  document.getElementById("loop-k").innerHTML = "Loop K: " + ktotal;
  document.getElementById("loop-l").innerHTML = "Loop L: " + ltotal;
  document.getElementById("loop-j").innerHTML = "Loop J: " + jtotal;
  document.getElementById("loops-total").innerHTML = "Total: " + totalgeral;
}
```

I would like to see the pictures changing with the impression they are spinning but just the first and the last picture show.

Any ideia will be greatly appreciated. I am learning so my code looks very simple and I still don't know how to use lots of features.

Comment: You have to give the browser time to actually render the changes. And that will only occur when the javascript stops executing. So if you do everything inside a loop, you'll only see the start and end states. You have to either use timeouts to schedule the changing of the pics, or use an animation. So I would write like a function that will start animating one of the slots and start it immediately, then start the other ones independantly every x seconds. Then when the last one stopped spinning, change to the final picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what loop to slow down but you could try to use `setTimeout` try something like this:

```
function myFunction() {

  var i, dicepic, duration = 0, interval = 1000;

  var itotal = ktotal = ltotal = jtotal = totalgeral = 0;

  var dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;

  for (i = 0; i < dice; i++) {

    itotal ++;
    totalgeral ++;

    var k;
      for (k = 1; k < 7; k++) {
        ktotal ++;
        totalgeral ++;
        setTimeout((function(){ this.src = 
'images/empire.jpg';}).bind(document.getElementById("first-picture" + k)), duration);
duration += interval;
      }

      var l;
      for (l = 1; l < 7; l++) {
        ltotal ++;
        totalgeral ++;
setTimeout((function(){ this.src = 
'images/black.jpg';}).bind(document.getElementById("first-picture" + l)), duration);
duration += interval;
      }

    var j;
    for (j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
      jtotal ++;
      totalgeral ++;
      var dicepic = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1;

setTimeout((function(){ 
this.el.src = this.pic;
document.getElementById("vari1").innerHTML = "Value of i is: " + this.i;
      document.getElementById("vari2").innerHTML = "Value of Dice is: " + 
this.dice;
      document.getElementById("pic-code-" + j).innerHTML = "Code is: " + 
this.dicepic;

}).bind({el:document.getElementById("first-picture" + j), pic: 'images/image' + 
dicepic + '.jpg', i: i, dice: dice, dicepic: dicepic}), duration);
duration += interval;

    }

  }
  document.getElementById("vari3").innerHTML = "Value of Dice is: " + 
dice;

  document.getElementById("loop-i").innerHTML = "Loop I: " + itotal;
  document.getElementById("loop-k").innerHTML = "Loop K: " + ktotal;
  document.getElementById("loop-l").innerHTML = "Loop L: " + ltotal;
  document.getElementById("loop-j").innerHTML = "Loop J: " + jtotal;
  document.getElementById("loops-total").innerHTML = "Total: " + 
totalgeral;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It does slow down the loop but unfortunatelly does not change the pictures, I believe something is wrong. Still trying to find out.

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure you have the right ids on images like `<img id="first-picture1" /><img id="first-picture2" /> ...` they way your code is you need to have 7 images.

Comment: I do have 11 images and 6 slots where I display them choosen randonly and it was working before but with your code this loop does not work. I will redo this part to see if I can find any mistakes there.

Comment: Your code is great, unfortunatelly only works with the same picture, I have tried everything but if I change the pictures it does not work,

Comment: Do you have sample code that I can work with. I can fix it for you.

Comment: function myFunction() {
  var i, dicepic, duration = 0, interval = 1000;
  var dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
  for (i = 0; i < dice; i++) {
    var j;
    for (j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
      var dicepic = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1;
      setTimeout((function(){ 
        this.src = this.pic;
        document.getElementById("pic-code-" + j).innerHTML = "Code is: " + this.dicepic;
     }).bind({el:document.getElementById("first-picture" + j), pic: 'images/image' + dicepic + '.jpg', i: i, dice: dice, dicepic: dicepic}), duration);
        duration += interval;}
}
}

Comment: For some reason when we use "this." it stops working. all other loops work fine but then they only have one image, this one is the one that will grab new images every time and update the page. Thanks again.

Comment: @Edson I think I have forgotten to update `this` element reference in side the setTimeout callback function. Replace the `this.src = this.pic;` with `this.el.src = this.pic;` I have updated the response code let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I should have realized that but I am still learning and somehow finding it quite difficult. It is working now. Thank you so much for all your help. Happy new year,

Comment: @Edson You are welcome! I'm glad I can help. Happy new year to you. You should mark this as a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping, which doesn’t guarantee control is given back to the rendering subprocess on each update, try using iterative function calls:

```
const YOUR_DELAY = 10;
function doTheThing(i) {
  if (i === 0) return;
  // step
  setTimeout(() => doTheThing(i - 1), YOUR_DELAY);
}

doTheThing(5);
```

Comment: Put the contents of any of your `for` loops in where I have `// step`. Call the function with `6`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does work but becomes an infinite loop. I will have material to study for months, lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code belwo to aniamate or call your function with FPS.

```
function AnimationLoop(fn, fps) {
    let now;
    let delta;
    let interval;
    let then = new Date().getTime();

    let frames;
    let oldtime = 0;

    return (function loop(time) {
        requestAnimationFrame(loop);

        interval = 1000 / (fps || 60);
        now = new Date().getTime();
        delta = now - then;
        if (delta > interval) {
            then = now - (delta % interval);
            frames = 1000 / (time - oldtime)
            oldtime = time;
            fn(frames);
        }
    }(0));
};

let counter = 10;
function countdown() {
    counter--;
    console.log(counter);
}

AnimationLoop(function(fps){
    countdown();
}, 1); // 1 is FPS, 1 Frame per Second, If you do it, 5 it will call your function 5 times in a second.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am a bit confused. How do I call my function from inside your function?

Comment: Or do I use your function to return a delay for my function? I tried several ways and they don't work. Sorry for being a pain.

Comment: You see `countdown` function in my snippet. You write your function insted of my `countdown` function and you should to call your function inside `AnimationLoop()` function call, so you will be on it :)

Comment: It does work but I have no control of the function. It starts automatically when I load the page, I need that it waits until I click the buttom start. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You can set a global variable, on top of your code for `start = false;`, if it false, don't call anything inside AnimationLoop function with if statement, if not, start.